# Will Bower install dependencies of a component?

Tags: bower

I was wondering if Bower will install the dependencies of the component I'm installing. Lets say I install a component which requires jQuery. Will Bower also install jQuery?

Comment: you will have to download jquery

Comment: Please think through what you want to ask and be clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bower will install the jQuery dependency for you if the component you installed have a bower.json with jQuery defined as a dependency.

Comment: Does this mean that in my HTML, I'll have to include <script> tags for both the component I want + the newly installed jquery component?

If so, that seems prone to errors because that means I have to check if all my bower dependencies have their own dependencies I need to include; however, I don't see how else this could be implemented.